# Null Pointer Exception when Creating Object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I was wondering is someone could help me figure out this null pointer exception. I'm making a program to find all anagrams of an English word. I've created a class EnglishDictionary that, when given the length of an English word along with its first letter, scans a text file containing all English words and selects add those that are the same length and contain the first letter to an ArrayList. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EnglishDictionary {

    public EnglishDictionary(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        processDict(firstLetter, wordLength);
    }

    public void processDict(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
        try {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader("englishWords.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    if (line.length() == wordLength) {
                        words.add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist.");
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void printWords() {
        for (String word : words) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> words;

}
```

As you can see, I haven't yet added the functionality of checking whether or not the first letter is in the selected English words. When I create an EnglishDictionary object from another class, I get a null pointer exception. It says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EnglishDictionary.processDict(EnglishDictionary.java:23)
    at EnglishDictionary.<init>(EnglishDictionary.java:10)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I can't seem to figure out where this is coming from. Can anyone else see? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And a good answer doesn't deserve any vote. What happened these days.

Answer (score 6):

`words` is not initialized correctly.  You are initializing a *LOCAL* variable words which is hiding the *CLASS* variable words.

Do this in your constructor:

```
public EnglishDictionary(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
  //ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();  // Creates a local variable called 'words'; class member does NOT get initialized.
  words = new ArrayList<String>(); // THIS initializes the class variable.
  processDict(firstLetter, wordLength);
```

}

Comment: I have already answered same thing before 4 minutes. :) Isn't it?

Comment: Your answer does not explain that the problem is that the local variable is hiding the class member.

Comment: I think you have taken it in wrong way. It was by mistake did by OP. OP was not trying to create a local variable without using it anywhere. And always try to leave a comment when you **down vote** next time. I have explained it in details already.

Comment: Yes, it was clearly a mistake, but one that is subtle and hard to see.  IMHO, it would be easy for someone to look at the code and think that the variable was initialized without realizing that there was a scoping problem.

Comment: Do you understand instance variable? If yes then OP also understand the same terminology. I have highlighted exact line no as well with the inline comments.

Comment: I think it's clear from my answer that I do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55009/discussion-between-peter-gluck-and-braj).

Comment: Sorry I don't want to discuss with you.

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution 1

It should be like this. Instance variable  `words` is not initialized.

```
public EnglishDictionary(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
    words = new ArrayList<String>();           // THIS LINE IS CHANGED
    processDict(firstLetter, wordLength);
}
```

#### Solution 2

Initialize at time of declaration of instance member to avoid `NullPointerException`.

```
private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

public EnglishDictionary(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
    //ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();    //REMOVE THIS LINE
    processDict(firstLetter, wordLength);
}
```

#### Solution 3

For safer side make it **`final`** to avoid such type of issues that will be **caught at compile time**.

```
private final ArrayList<String> words;
```

---

The problem is here `words.add(line);` because `words` is not initialized at all.

Comment: **Downvoter** never forget to leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a problem of scope.

Your method:

```
public EnglishDictionary(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    processDict(firstLetter, wordLength);
}
```

instantiates ArrayList words, however the scope of words is only visible to this method. Hence when calling words in another method you get an error.

You can fix this by moving Arraylist words outside of the method, and just instantiating it inside your method:

```
ArrayList<String> words;


public EnglishDictionary(String firstLetter, int wordLength) {
    words = new ArrayList<String>();
    processDict(firstLetter, wordLength);
}
```

Comment: Look at the last line of the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

In constructor change `ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();` to `words = new ArrayList<String>();`

In first case you are creating a local arraylist named 'word' whose scope is only withing constructor. But you actually need to initialize the instance variable 'word'